# Why is GPflow's Scipy optimizer incompatible with decorating the optimization step with tf.function?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, gpflow

I am supplying different minibatches to optimize a GPflow model (SVGP). If I decorate the `optimization_step` with `tf.function` I get the following error:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (concat:0) to a
> numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a
> Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

In order for the optimizer to run I had to remove the `tf.function` decorator, losing the speed-up advantages. What do I need to change so that I can keep using the `tf.function` decorator?

The `xAndY` input shapes and types are all `numpy` arrays.

```py
type(xAndY)
Out[71]: tuple
xAndY[0].shape
Out[72]: (245760, 2)
xAndY[1].shape
Out[73]: (245760, 1)
type(xAndY[0])
Out[74]: numpy.ndarray
```

```py
def run_optimizer_on_minibatch_size(model, iterations, minibatch_size, xAndY):
    """
    Utility function running a Scipy optimizer
    :param model: GPflow model
    :param interations: number of iterations
    """
    N = xAndY[0].shape[0]
    tensor_data = tuple(map(tf.convert_to_tensor, xAndY))
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor_data).repeat().shuffle(N)
    
    logf = []
    train_iter = iter(train_dataset.batch(minibatch_size))
    training_loss = model.training_loss_closure(train_iter, compile=True)
    optimizer = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()

    @tf.function   # had to remove this decorator
    def optimization_step():
        optimizer.minimize(training_loss, model.trainable_variables)

    # step = 0
    for step in range(iterations):
        optimization_step()
        if step % 10 == 0:
            elbo = -training_loss().numpy()
            logf.append(elbo)
            print(elbo)
    return logf

from gpflow.ci_utils import ci_niter
maxiter = ci_niter(20000)
logf = run_optimizer_on_minibatch_size(m, maxiter, minibatch_size, (X,Y))
```

Comment: [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function), Compiles a function into a callable TensorFlow graph, so it just accept a tensor type. you could use  [tf.cast](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast)

Comment: I thought the line `tensor_data = tuple(map(tf.convert_to_tensor, xAndY))` did that already. Maybe missing another conversion somewhere...

Comment: `train_iter = iter(train_dataset.batch(minibatch_size))`, this also should case the same issue, In general tensorflow-graph can't deal with a non-tensorflow code directly

Comment: [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function), restrictions inside its scope, so all python code inside `run_optimizer_on_minibatch_size(...)`, is fine, try to cast  `optimizer.minimize(training_loss, model.trainable_variables)`, parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPflow's `gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()` is a wrapper around Scipy's minimize(), and as it calls into non-TensorFlow operations, you cannot wrap it in `tf.function`. Moreover, the optimizers implemented in Scipy's minimize are second-order methods that assume that your gradients are *not* stochastic, and aren't compatible with minibatching.

If you want to do full-batch optimization with Scipy: The `minimize()` method of `gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()`, by default, does wrap the objective and gradient computation inside `tf.function` (see its `compile` argument with default `True`). It also does the full optimization, so you only have to call the `minimize()` method *once* (by default it runs until convergence or failure to continue optimization; you can supply a maximum number of iterations using the `options=dict(maxiter=1000)` argument).

If you want to use mini-batching: simply use one of the TensorFlow optimizers, such as `tf.optimizers.Adam()`, and then your code should run fine including the `@tf.function` decorator on your `optimization_step()` function (and in that case you do need to call it in a loop as in your example).